# 文字列をUnicodeに変換できない

Tags: android, java, unicode

Unicodeにうまく変換できません。

```
private EditText unicodeText;
private byte[] stringchar;
ByteBuffer bytebuffer;
CharBuffer charbuffer;

public void onClick(View v){
    this.unicodeText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.unicode);

    bytebuffer=ByteBuffer.wrap(text.getText().toString().getBytes());//クラス外にtextという変数名のEditTextがある
    CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder(); 
    try{
        charbuffer=decoder.decode(bytebuffer);
    }
    catch (CharacterCodingException e){Exception(e);}
    //処理をException()にまとめて書いている
    this.unicodeText.setText(charbuffer.toString());
}
```

どこが悪いか教えて下さい。

Comment: 「Unicodeに変換する」というのは具体的にどのような入力から、どのような出力を得ることを期待されているのでしょうか？

Comment: String型の普通の文章からUnicodeが出力されるようにしたいです。例としては"あ"→\u3042(¥u3042)のようにしたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**　コードの一部にバグがあったため修正（7/3）

`\u3042`のような記法は、Unicodeエスケープ文字などの呼び方がされます。[Unicode](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)とは規格名です。

`"あ"`という文字から、`3042`という文字コードを得るのは`charAt()`で取得した文字コードを16進数化すればいいので、

```
public void onClick(View v){
    this.unicodeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.unicode);
    String input = text.getText().toString();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
        // 元版は0x1000以下の文字コードを正しくUTF-16化していなかったので修正
        builder.append("\\u" + Integer.toHexString(text.charAt(i) | 0x10000).substring(1));
    }
    this.unicodeText.setText(result.toString());       
}
```

このようなコードになります。

サロゲートペアを考慮しなければならない場合にはもう少し複雑なコードになります。

#### 参考

- [Java 言語による Unicode サロゲート・プログラミング](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/java/library/j-unicode/)

Comment: なるほど。なら逆にUnicodeエスケープに変換するなら、16進数をStringに変換すればいいのですね。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

このような方法もあるみたいです。

```
String input = "あ"; //ここは何でも良い
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        result.append("\\u").append(String.format("%04x", (int) input.charAt(i)));
    }
String unicode = result.toString(); //unicodeの値は'\\u3042'
```

### 理由

16進数を4桁にして0x1000より小さいコードをサポートするため。

Comment: 訳とありますが、原文がどこかにあるのでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist さん、「訳」は「やく」ではなく「わけ」でしょう。Java言語の文字列リテラルやJSONのユニコードエスケープでは必ず4桁の16進数が必要であることを言っているのだと思います。コード値が0x0FFFまでだと、3桁以下になって文法上正しいとみなされなくなりますから。せっかく重要な補足をつけていただいているのだから、もう少しわかりやすい表現にしてもらえたら嬉しいですね。

Comment: Stringの内部表現はUTF-16ですので、値の取りえる範囲は0x0000～0xFFFFまでですね！失礼しました。

Comment: @unarist わけ です。失礼しました。理由に修正しました。

Comment: 理由については自分もよく分かっていません。ただ、こうした方がいいよと指摘されたので引用しました。